# VTD-XML: XPath Statement - if(10 > 5) then "yes" else "no"

Tags: xpath, vtd-xml

With VTD-XML, is it possible to execute the following XPath statement?

> if(10 > 5) then "yes" else "no"`

I have a much more complex statement, but it will not run with my current setup.  There are these methods possible:  `evalXPathToBoolean()`, `evalXPathToNumber()`, and `evalXpathToString()`.  But, I am receiving this error when trying to execute:

> com.ximpleware.extended.XPathParseExceptionHuge: XPath Syntax error: #8

```
autoPilot.selectXPath(xpath) // does not like this
while((i=autoPilot.evalXPath())!=-1){        
list.add(vtdNav.toString(i));
}
```

This is valid XPath and works in XMLSpy.  Is it possible to do this with VTD-XML?  Please advise.

Comment: Please note, I know that I could use evalXPathToBoolean() to return true or false, but the conditional logic is much more complex and, ultimately, a string will have to be returned based upon another XPath statement that will be run.

Answer (score 0):

VTD-XML supports full set of XPath 1.0. The syntax you alluded to is likely XPath 2.0 syntax... which is not supported by VTD-XML at this point.

The solution/work-around is to take your conditional statement and code it into your application logic, and only use VTD-XML XPath boolean/number evaluation capability to obtain the values , which you can then weave into your condition logic...